# How to debug the distorted image in real iPhone 12?

Tags: iphone, google-chrome-devtools

I find a strange issue. When loading a page in my iPhone, the image is distorted, as below:

[image]

However, if test in Chrome DevTools, the the image will NOT distorted any more, as below:

[image]

How to solve such an issue?